# Format output from nested for loops

Tags: python, loops, nested, formatting

I am trying to get this to print almost like a grid but without the | character at the end of each row. I only want that character to appear between the numbers, with a single space on each side of it.  The issue is the final bar at the end of each row. I want everything else the same. Similar question on here does not provide the answer as it removes the final column of numbers, rather than just the | character.

Here is the relevant part of the code (it's from an exercise in zybooks)

mult_table = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]

for row_index, row in enumerate(mult_table):
for column_index, num in enumerate(row):
print((num), '|', end=' ')
print()

```
The highlighted part of this shows the issue:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xru01.png
```

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate()`? You never use the indexes for anything.

Comment: `print('|' if column_index else '', num, end=' ')`

Comment: I thought it was necessary to iterate through each of the items in the mult_table.  I am new to python, so excuse my awkward programming.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thanks. I tried that but now I am getting leading and trailing spaces that the exercise doesn't want either.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `' | '.join(row)`? This would simplify things but would require that you get rid of the cast to `int(...)`. Though one can force it by `' | '.join([str(c) for c in row])`.